# How do I fix this error in my log-linear regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run a log-linear regression in R:

```r
model1 <- log(Sales_Price) ~ Sale_Year + Total_Assessed_Value + Property_Type 
           + Lot_Size + Year_Built + SQFT + Px_SF + Bedrooms + Bathrooms +  Fireplaces

plot(model1)
```

The model runs and can be found in the environment, but when I try to plot the model I receive an error saying that a variable is not found:

> `Error: object 'Lot_Size' not found`

So when I remove `Lot_Size` for example, R says that another variable can't be found:

> `Error: object 'Year_Built' not found`

The data is correctly read into the system because I can check what format the variables are in using the 'str' command:

```r
str(All_Porter_Data)
```

All variables are in numeric format. Other than the variables not being in numerical format or the data itself not being read into the system, I don't know what the error could be.

Comment: The object `model1` is a model formula. To actually fit the model you would need to do `mymodel = lm(model1, data=All_Porter_Data)`. Then, `mymodel` is the fitted model object.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I try to plot model1 using this code I still return the not found error. Any other ideas?

Comment: The same idea. Read the answer carefully, plot(mymodel) not plot(model1).